# Where can I find a transformer that will step up a 12v input to around 400v?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, ultrasound, transducer

So i'm trying to build an ultrasonic levitator by following the build on mike's electric stuff's channel h ttps://youtu.be/qy1w6rTpC2g . I've set everything up same as he did, following the schematic. [image: Ultrasonic Levitator Schematic]

I'm using a standard power supply rated 12V 0-6A. When I power it up and have my oscilliscope attatched to the output of the FET I get a square wave that looks like this. [image: Square Wave]

It seems to look ok to me. I've gone through a load of old ATX power supplies to find transformers but no matter how I connct them to my driver circuit it has no affect on the transducer and I've tried absolutely every combination of pins and windings possible many times. Sometimes I get the same voltage at Vin and Vout, sometimes Vout is arround 40v but I've never been able to get it high enough to drive the transducer correctly. Is there any where I can buy a transformer that will suit this purpose as an individual component or what other appliances could I potentially scavenge one from ? or have I done something completely wrong? I am quite new to electronics.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Other than a 120V-to-3.6V or 240V-to-7.2V transformer?

Comment: Take a look at this previous answer to a similar issue:
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70143/dc-dc-converter-12v-to-400v-is-this-possible

Comment: How much current? You can roll your own boost supply with a handful of components to generate 400V from 12V, sufficient to drive a ultrasonic piezo transducer, but not much more.

Comment: Yep, I second the custom flyback or boost converter... Now days sites like TI will do all the design for you...

Comment: A PSU transformer may be a possible first approximation.  However you only have 72W of power supply available (well half actually with your unipolar drive) and your ATX PSU may have been rated for 100-500W and might be overloading your drive circuit.  It may not be optimised for your drive frequency.  Also not that the ultrasonic energy may be slightly dangerous to soft tissue (fingers, brains etc).  Acoustic coupling impedance must also be considered.  I would start from a cheap ultrasonic cleaner or ornamental fountain mist maker if frequency and power are acceptable.

Comment: That output waveform is wrong - for a 12V supply you should be seeing 24V p-p. Also, what operating frequency is this? If it's about 2 kHz then using an old AC mains transformer is not going to work too well because of eddy current losses in the laminates at the significantly higher frequency. Roll your own is my advice - what ferrites can you buy?

Answer (score 1):

Your driving frequency(from the oscilloscope plot) seems to be too low for ultrasound. The ATX PSU transformer is designed to work at more than 25khz and will have a low impedance at your frequency causing it to overload the power supply. This might explain the low Vp-p of the output waveform.

Since you are new to electronics, I wouldn't recommend building this circuit due to the risk of high voltage and damage from ultrasound.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a reason you can think of for why the driver board isn't producing the correct frequency ?